# Can we have the two DSL language with same extension?

Tags: dsl

I am developing a tool, and there are lots of Domain classes. I want to divide them in the different DSL's with same extension.

So it is possible to have multiple DSL projects with same extension?

And also after building the setup of all the dsl can we view all the Domain Classes of different DSL projects with same extension in Toolbar of one solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the DSL forum on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dslvsarchx/threads